# Bootstrap and CSS won't work with WAMPSERVER?

Tags: wampserver

I tried to run my code with atom-live-server and it works beautifully.

[with atom-live-server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jD3AY.png):

[image: with atom live server]

However, when I switch to WAMPSERVER my code just doesn't work?
[something went wrong with Wampserver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4fYa.png):

[image]

I am using the latest version of Wampserver and latest version of bootstrap (4.)

And when I inspect the html code on browser it looks like this:
[HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyOvl.png)

I use alias directory that names "phuocsonwebsite" like this: [alias directory which contains my project folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjHyi.png)

It seems that my problem is Wamp Alias did not automatically change the Url path of Bootstrap so that there are some error that can be viewed with the Network Tab of my browser: [Founded Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4l08.png)

As you can see, other elements are automatically added in the path by "phuocsonwebsite" BUT the bootstrap does not! How can I fix this?

Comment: Inspect the HTML code on browser and check the styles path sources.

Comment: I did, and I edited the question to add the image of my html code, would you mind having a look?? What's wrong with it?

Comment: Write the HTML code in the question, do not paste it as an image. What URL do you use to access the website from wamp? What's your folder structure?

Comment: @azeós I use an Alias Directory which contains my project folder, and I use exact the URL to that alias directory. I will edit my post to make it clear.

Comment: Presumably, the URL to your CSS isn't resolving right. Use the Network tab in your browser's developer tools to debug it.

Comment: Ahh, thank you @Quentin I see my bootstrap and jquery seem to have some errors. I will google and try to fix it. Thank you

Comment: Hello, I still stuck here, I cannot debug it!, I added new information on my post, please help me!

Answer (score 0):

it works perfectly fine. Follow the steps below to run the project in Wamp:

1. First, rename the existing www folder
2. Place the project folder in the wamp server directory and rename it to www
3. Run it by entering localhost in your browser